# ember new router

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a question about Ember routing and controllers. I've just written a small App to get familiar with the new router. Therefore I've built a button that transitions to another state by  clicking on it.

```
App.PostsView = Em.View.extend({
  click: function() {
    var router;
    this.get('controller').transitionTo('about');
  }
});
```

My question now is: **what does the `get` method return?**. Obviously an instance of the `PostController` but on the one hand the controller doesn't have a `transitionTo()` method and on the other hand that would not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.get('foo')` returns a property of your Ember object. Since Views can have a "controller" property, `this.get('controller')` returns the controller bound to your view's controller property (by default the postsController).

`this.get('controller').transitionTo()` works because as sly7_7 mentioned, `transitionTo()` is also defined on the controller and delegates to the router. Note, it's probably going to be deprecated and one should use

```
this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('about');
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this at the view level, this is what the router is designed for so instead of capturing a click event in the view, rather implement an action on the button and let the router handle it. I suggest you learn the best practices from the get-go, chances are your application will evolve, requiring more elaborate concepts such as handling transactions commits/rollbacks, creating/updating records. So here's my suggestion to you

In your view

```
<button type="button" {{action onSaveClick}} />Save</button>
```

In your router

```
App.FooRoute = App.Route.extend({
    events: {
        onSaveClick: function() {
            this.transitionTo('bar');
        }
    }
})
```

If for any other reasons, say styling or animation, you find yourself forced to capture the click event in the view, then i suggest to, capture the event, perform your styling and finally send an event to the controller. The event can then be handled the same way in the router

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
 click: function() {
   // Do some styling
   this.get('controller').send('onSaveClick')
 }
})
```

Finally speaking of best practices, try to learn when working with ember to think of your application as a series of states interacting with each other. You'll find yourself *bound* to implement the concept right. Have a look at [this](https://speakerdeck.com/trek/applications-a-series-of-states)

Comment: First of all thank you all for the very quick and detailed help. I was just looking on the documentation at the ember site and there i didn't find the 'transitionTo' function. @ken thanks for your advices i appreciate it. Anyway this was just a small practise to get used to the new router.

Answer (score 1):

the controller has a transitionTo: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/ext/controller.js#L36, it basically delegate to it's target (which is the router)